# Number of messages flowed through queue

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I have Queue A. I have used this in one of my message flow which is up and running. I want to know the number of message dropped in to the queue A on particular day or time interval.

Kindly help me in finding out this.

Answer (score 5):

Please have a look at the product manuals, in particular:

- [Queue statistics information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037360_.htm?lang=en) tells how to enable queue statistics and ensure that you are collecting all the relevant data.
- [Displaying accounting and statistics information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037390_.htm?lang=en) which explains, well, pretty much what the title says.
- And to keep this on-topic for Stack Overflow, check out the [Statistics messages format](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037330_.htm?lang=en) page which tells you how to programmatically access the queue stats messages.  By writing your own code to collect the messages, you can store them to a database, save them off to a file, slice and dice the numbers for pie charts, whatever.

You did not mention which version of MQ that you are using and that is usually important.  However, all modern versions of MQ have some queue stats instrumentation.  The links I provided are from the v8.0 Knowledge Center.

Comment: Queue Accounting and Statistics were added in MQ V6.0, so all modern and supported versions of MQ will be able to do this.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't remember which version those were added in or if they have been enhanced much since then.